# SoapClient->__call late resonse time while using api services

Tags: php

I am using api service to get flight details and there is a line of code

```
$options = array('compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP);
$cliente = new SoapClient($wsdl,$options);
$flight_result = $cliente->__call('getAvailability',array($opta));
```

`$flight_result` code takes almost 1 min to get all response. there is any alternate function of Soapclient. is there is any way to get result in array or in XML so i can show result while getting response.i wanted to reduce resonse time.its important
thank in advance.

Comment: If you want to reduce response time, then you should *reduce response time*. Which is not related to anything a SoapClient does - this is your server that's the problem (unless you can prove otherwise).

Comment: Also, please format your code.